# what would be the best case scenario of merging two sorted array?

Tags: arrays, merge, time-complexity

i know that merging two sorted array takes O(m+n) time where m and n are the length of two arrays.

maximum number of comparison would be (m+n-1).

But one of my school teacher said that only average and worst case takes O(m+n) time. best cases takes O(1) time.

here i am not able to understand how best case takes O(1).
please mention best case scenario and how it takes O(1) time while answering .

Comment: Are you sure he talked about arrays, not linked lists?

Comment: yes .. talked about arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first consider the best-case complexity of determining the correct order of the elements in two sorted sets (without worrying about how they are stored).

If the last element in the first set is smaller than the first element in the second set, only a single comparison is needed to determine the correct order.   The second set just needs to be "tacked on" to the end of the first set.  (Most implementations would start from the front of both sets, but you could write this as a "special case" check at the beginning of the sort.)

Since this case takes only a single comparison, regardless of the number of elements in the arrays, determining the correct order in the best-case is O(1).

---

Now, back to the problem where the elements are stored in arrays...

In many languages, arrays cannot be resized once created - merging two arrays would require allocating a third array that is large enough to contain all of the elements.  If this is the case, you're guaranteed to perform at least `m + n` operations because you have to copy all the elements into a new array.

Even if one the first array can be resized to accommodate additional elements, all of those elements still have to be copied from the second array to the first - that's still `n` operations.

So, while determining the correct order could be done in a constant number of comparisons, the amount of work to move the elements still yields O(n) in the best case.

Comment: Thanks BJ Myers . it means  there will be no O(1) time complexity  for merging two sorted array if we use secondary array. but i believe that if we use linklist then we can achieve O(1) complexity in as per your best case.